# Spring + Thymeleaf - how to implement pagination for a list

Tags: spring, pagination, thymeleaf

I am developing a simple application using Spring + Thymeleaf. On one of the pages I have a list of items which needs to be paginated.

Ideally I would like to only send the `currPageNo` (the number of the current page) and `numOfPages` (the total number of pages) variables to the view and the rest of the work would be done in there (this is a presentation issue and has nothing to do with the business logic). If, however, the cleanest solution would require me to do some computation in the controller first, I would accept it as a small evil.

I would like to get the list of pages in the following form.

```
<Prev | 1 | ... | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | ... | 15 | Next>
```

I was only able to come with the following solution. It works but I believe that you will agree that it is very messy and really hard to read.

Moreover, in addition to `currPageNo` and `numOfPages` I had to send two more variables to the view. The ideal solution would not require me to do that.

```
firstPageNo = Math.max(2, currPageNo - 2)
lastPageNo = Math.min(numOfPages - 1, currPageNo + 2)
```

The current version of my code follows.

```
<ul>
    <li th:if="${currPageNo &gt; 1}">
        <a th:href="@{/items.html(pageNo = ${currPageNo - 1})}" href="">&lt; Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li th:class="${currPageNo == 1} ? 'selected'">
        <a th:href="@{/items.html(pageNo = 1)}" th:if="${currPageNo &gt; 1}" href="">1</a>
        <span th:if="${currPageNo == 1}">1</span>
    </li>
    <li th:if="${currPageNo &gt;= 5}">
        ...
    </li>
    <li th:each="pageNo : ${#numbers.sequence(firstPageNo, lastPageNo)}"  th:class="${currPageNo == pageNo} ? 'selected'">
        <a th:href="@{/items.html(pageNo = ${pageNo})}" th:if="${pageNo != currPageNo}" th:text="${pageNo}" href="">2</a>
        <span th:if="${pageNo == currPageNo}" th:text="${pageNo}">2</span>
    </li>
    <li th:if="${currPageNo &lt;= (numOfPages - 4)}">
        ...
    </li>
    <li th:class="${currPageNo == numOfPages} ? 'selected'">
        <a th:href="@{/items.html(pageNo = ${numOfPages})}" th:if="${currPageNo &lt; numOfPages}" th:text="${numOfPages}" href="">10</a>
        <span th:if="${currPageNo == numOfPages}" th:text="${numOfPages}">1</span>
    </li>
    <li th:if="${currPageNo &lt; numOfPages}">
        <a th:href="@{/items.html(pageNo = ${currPageNo + 1})}" href=""> Next &gt;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The following list sumarizes the issues that I would like to get rid of the most. I understand that some of them are inherent to the platform but still, the list seems to be quit long and the code messy.

- Having to send the precomputed values of `firstPageNo` and `lastPageNo` to the view from the controller.
- Having to use `&lt;` instead of `<` in the expressions.
- Having to use both an anchor and a span with mutually exclusive conditions in order for the browser not to use a link for the current page.

I also welcome any other suggestions about how to improve the quality of the code.

---

I understand that perhaps this question would be a better fit for the Code Review site, but, as Thymeleaf seems to be a technology with a tiny user base yet, I expect a reasonable answer rather here on Stack Overflow, which has a much greater user base (I believe).

If, however, such a question is really not welcome here, please consider moving it to the right site instead of closing it so that I get the advice I need.

Answer (score 21):

Similar to solution described in
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/implement-bootstrap-pagination-with-spring-data-and-thymeleaf.html

but without using wrapper around Spring Pageable

```
<div class="table-pagination">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li th:class="${contactsPage.number eq 0} ? 'disabled' : ''">
            <a th:if="${not contactsPage.firstPage}" th:href="@{${'/contacts'}(page=${contactsPage.number-1},size=${contactsPage.size})}">Previous</a>
            <a th:if="${contactsPage.firstPage}" href="javascript:void(0);">Previous</a>
        </li>

        <li th:each="pageNo : ${#numbers.sequence(0, contactsPage.totalPages - 1)}" th:class="${contactsPage.number eq pageNo}? 'active' : ''">
            <a th:if="${contactsPage.number  eq pageNo}" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <span th:text="${pageNo + 1}"></span>
            </a>
            <a th:if="${not (contactsPage.number  eq pageNo)}" th:href="@{${'/contacts'}(page=${pageNo},size=${contactsPage.size})}">
                <span th:text="${pageNo + 1}"></span>
            </a>

        </li>
        <li th:class="${contactsPage.number + 1 ge contactsPage.totalPages} ? 'disabled' : ''">
            <a th:if="${not contactsPage.lastPage}" th:href="@{${'/contacts'}(page=${contactsPage.number+1},size=${contactsPage.size})}">Next</a>
            <a th:if="${contactsPage.lastPage}" href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include some text such as an explanation with code.

Comment: Don't just dump code... add some meat to it as well.

Comment: Note as of now you have to replace `firstPage` and `lastPage` with `first` and `last`.

Comment: how to do it user friendly when there are many pages. (more than 100 for ex.)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be Ben Thurley's solution. We have implemented it and it's working smoothly: http://bthurley.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/spring-mvc-with-restful-datatables/

It lacks couples of items, like the filter argument for the search, but you can easily add via the PagingCriteria object and make sure to add it on the TableParamArgumentResolver.

```
public class TableParamArgumentResolver implements WebArgumentResolver {

    private static final String S_ECHO           = "sEcho";
    private static final String I_DISPLAY_START  = "iDisplayStart";
    private static final String I_DISPLAY_LENGTH = "iDisplayLength";
    private static final String I_SORTING_COLS   = "iSortingCols";

    private static final String I_SORT_COLS      = "iSortCol_";
    private static final String S_SORT_DIR       = "sSortDir_";
    private static final String S_DATA_PROP      = "mDataProp_";
    private static final String I_DATA_SEARCH    = "sSearch";

    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter param, NativeWebRequest request)
            throws Exception {
        TableParam tableParamAnnotation = param.getParameterAnnotation(TableParam.class);

        if (tableParamAnnotation != null) {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request.getNativeRequest();

            String sEcho = httpRequest.getParameter(S_ECHO);
            String sDisplayStart = httpRequest.getParameter(I_DISPLAY_START);
            String sDisplayLength = httpRequest.getParameter(I_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
            String sSortingCols = httpRequest.getParameter(I_SORTING_COLS);
            String sSearch = httpRequest.getParameter(I_DATA_SEARCH);

            Integer iEcho = Integer.parseInt(sEcho);
            Integer iDisplayStart = Integer.parseInt(sDisplayStart);
            Integer iDisplayLength = Integer.parseInt(sDisplayLength);
            Integer iSortingCols = Integer.parseInt(sSortingCols);

            List<SortField> sortFields = new ArrayList<SortField>();
            for (int colCount = 0; colCount < iSortingCols; colCount++) {
                String sSortCol = httpRequest.getParameter(I_SORT_COLS + colCount);
                String sSortDir = httpRequest.getParameter(S_SORT_DIR + colCount);
                String sColName = httpRequest.getParameter(S_DATA_PROP + sSortCol);
                sortFields.add(new SortField(sColName, sSortDir));
            }

            PagingCriteria pc = new PagingCriteria(iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength, iEcho, sortFields, sSearch);

            return pc;
        }

        return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.
As a result, it will look like this[image]

Controller:
[image]

```
 @GetMapping("/myPage")
public String main(
        @PageableDefault(sort = {"id"}, direction = Sort.Direction.ASC, value = 100) Pageable pageable,
        Model model) {
    Page<myData> page;

    page = boardgameService.findAll(pageable);

    int[] body;
    if (page.getTotalPages() > 7) {
        int totalPages = page.getTotalPages();
        int pageNumber = page.getNumber()+1;
        int[] head = (pageNumber > 4) ? new int[]{1, -1} : new int[]{1,2,3};
        int[] bodyBefore = (pageNumber > 4 && pageNumber < totalPages - 1) ? new int[]{pageNumber-2, pageNumber-1} : new int[]{};
        int[] bodyCenter = (pageNumber > 3 && pageNumber < totalPages - 2) ? new int[]{pageNumber} : new int[]{};
        int[] bodyAfter = (pageNumber > 2 && pageNumber < totalPages - 3) ? new int[]{pageNumber+1, pageNumber+2} : new int[]{};
        int[] tail = (pageNumber < totalPages - 3) ? new int[]{-1, totalPages} : new int[] {totalPages-2, totalPages-1, totalPages};
        body = ControllerUtils.merge(head, bodyBefore, bodyCenter, bodyAfter, tail);

    } else {
        body = new int[page.getTotalPages()];
        for (int i = 0; i < page.getTotalPages(); i++) {
            body[i] = 1+i;
        }
    }

    model.addAttribute("body", body);
    model.addAttribute("page", page);
    return "myPage";
}
```

ControllerUtils method "merge":

```
public static int[] merge(int[]... intarrays) {
    return Arrays.stream(intarrays).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
            .toArray();
}
```

And my pager.html

```
<div th:fragment="pager (pagination)">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <th:block th:each="pageNumber : ${body}">
            <li th:if="${pageNumberStat.first}" class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" th:href="${url} + '?page='+ ${page.getNumber()} + '&size=' + ${page.getSize()}" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item active" th:if="${pageNumber} == ${page.getNumber()+1}">
                <a class="page-link" th:text="${pageNumber}" href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item disabled" th:if="${pageNumber} == -1">
                <a class="page-link" href="#">...</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item" th:if="${pageNumber} != -1 and ${pageNumber} != ${page.getNumber()+1}">
                <a class="page-link" th:text="${pageNumber}" th:href="${url} + '?page='+ ${pageNumber} + '&size=' + ${page.getSize()}"></a>
            </li>
            <li th:if="${pageNumberStat.last}" class="page-item"  aria-label="Next">
                <a class="page-link" th:href="${url} + '?page='+ ${page.getNumber() + 2} + '&size=' + ${page.getSize()}">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </th:block>
    </ul>
```

I almost forgot the last moment. So that indexing does not start from 0, but from 1. In MvcConfig:

```
    @Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
    resolvers.add(resolver);
    WebMvcConfigurer.super.addArgumentResolvers(resolvers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this almost ready, hope it helps....

```
<div class="tag-box tag-box-v7 text-justify">
    <div class="text-center">
        <ul class="pagination" th:with="elementsperpage=2, blocksize=10, pages=${page2th.Number}/${elementsperpage}, wholepages=${format.format(pages)},
whole=(${page2th.Number}/${blocksize})+1, wholex=${format.format(whole)}, startnlockpage=${wholepages}*${blocksize+1}, endblockpage=${wholepages}*${blocksize+1}, 
startpage=${wholex-1}*${blocksize}, endpage=(${wholex}*${blocksize})+1">

            <li>
                <a th:if="${startpage gt 0}" th:href="@{${'/viewannouncements?p='}+${startpage}}">&lt;&lt;</a>
                <a th:if="${startpage eq 0}" href="javascript:void(0);">&lt;&lt;</a>
            </li>

            <li th:each="pageNo : ${#numbers.sequence(endpage-11, (endpage lt page2th.TotalPages)? endpage-2 : page2th.TotalPages-1)}" 
            th:class="${page2th.Number eq pageNo}? 'active' : ''">
                    <a th:if="${page2th.Number eq pageNo}" href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <span th:text="${pageNo + 1}"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a th:if="${not (page2th.Number  eq pageNo)}" th:href="@{${'/viewannouncements?p='}+${pageNo+1}}">
                        <span th:text="${pageNo + 1}"></span>
                    </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a th:if="${(endpage*elementsperpage) le (page2th.TotalElements)}" th:href="@{${'/viewannouncements?p='}+${endpage}}">&gt;&gt;</a>
                <a th:if="${(endpage*elementsperpage) le (page2th.TotalElements)}" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
            </li>



        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you use pageable interface

@GetMapping("/show-contacts/{page}")
public String showContacts(@PathVariable("page") Integer page, Model model, Principal principal) {

```
    model.addAttribute("title", "Show Contacts");
    
    //have to send contacts list
    String name = principal.getName();
    User user = this.userRepository.getUserByUserName(name);
            
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, 5);
    
    Page<Contact> contacts = this.contactRepository.findContactsByUser(user.getId(), pageable);

    model.addAttribute("contacts", contacts);
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    model.addAttribute("totalPages", contacts.getTotalPages());
    
    return "user/show_contacts";
}
```

Thymleaf

1

Answer (score 0):

The following fragment can be used in any template in the project as it uses **ServletUriComponentsBuilder** to figure out URL for each page, no changes in controller required.

You only need to provide page number in your URL (**/?page=X**) and inject **Page<myData>** object as template variable (here used as **"pagination"**). Any additional query string parameters will be automatically appended to chosen page.
The **max** variable defined as **th:with="max=3"** provides information how many pages should be shown before and after selected page.

Example screenshots:

- [first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsVqh.png)
- [middle page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUaIm.png)
- [last page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a5Cu.png)

```html
<th:block th:fragment="paginationLinks(pagination)" th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder)}">
    <nav aria-label="page navigation" th:if="${pagination.totalPages>1}" th:with="max=3">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item" th:if="${pagination.hasPrevious()}">
                <a class="page-link"
                   th:href="@{${urlBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().replaceQueryParam('page', pagination.number - 1).toUriString()}}"><i class="mdi mdi-arrow-left"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item" th:each="page: ${#numbers.sequence(0, pagination.totalPages-1)}"
                th:if="${pagination.number} >= ${page - max} and ${pagination.number} <= ${page + max} or ${page} == ${pagination.totalPages - 1} or ${page} == 0"
                th:classappend="${page} == ${pagination.number} ? 'active'">
                <span class="page-link" th:if="${pagination.number} == ${page + max} and ${page != 0}">...</span>
                <a class="page-link"
                   th:if="${pagination.number} > ${page - max} and ${pagination.number} < ${page + max} or ${page} == ${pagination.totalPages - 1} or ${page} == 0"
                   th:href="@{${urlBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().replaceQueryParam('page', page).toUriString()}}" th:text="${page+1}">1</a>
                <span class="page-link" th:if="${pagination.number} == ${page - max} and ${page} != ${pagination.totalPages - 1}">...</span>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item" th:if="${pagination.hasNext()}">
                <a class="page-link"
                   th:href="@{${urlBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().replaceQueryParam('page', pagination.number + 1).toUriString()}}"><i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</th:block>
```