# Next/Prev buttons to change object from list using Spring MVC and thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I've page `editPLayer` where I used Thymeleaf. I want add buttons Next and Previously to change information in forms about player.

Buttons like :

```
<input class="button2 button-switch" value="&lt;&lt;"/>
<input class="button2 button-switch" value="&gt;&gt;"/>
```

`editPlayer.html` loooks like that:

```
<div class="card">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/editPlayer}" th:object="${player}" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id_player}"></input>

            <div class="info">Name: </div>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Imie" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? 'error'" /><br/>

            <div class="info">Surname: </div>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{surname}" placeholder="Nazwisko" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('surname')}? 'error'" /><br/>

            <div class="info">Age: </div>   
            <input type="text" th:field="*{age}" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}? 'error'"/><br/>

            <div class="info">Number: </div>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{number}" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('number')}? 'error'"/><br/>

            <input type="submit" class="button button-submit" value="EDIT"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

in code above `player` is object returned from Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/editPlayer")
public class EditPlayerController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editPlayerForm(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("player", playerRepository.findOne((long) 1));

        return "editPlayer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editPlayerSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("player") Player player, 
            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, 
            HttpSession session){

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "editPlayer";
        }

        playerRepository.save(player);

        return "redirect:/coachSite";
    }
}
```

Now I add to model Player object with Id = 1 (in this line)

```
model.addAttribute("player", playerRepository.findOne((long) 1));
```

I want add to model List of players, like :

```
model.addAttribute("player", playerRepository.findAll());
```

... and in `editPlayer.html` placed switched button (Next and Prevoiusly) to show inf forms for example first user from list, click `Next`and show next user from list in forms. How can I do this ? Any idea ? Maybe somebody have nice idea using JavaScript ?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490820/spring-thymeleaf-how-to-implement-pagination-for-a-list

Comment: I dont need pages, only currently displayed object player and option to Next and Prevoius object, it must be show in my form int `editPlayer.html`. I don't know how implements this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont need pages, only currently displayed object player and option to Next and Prevoius object, it must be show in my form int editPlayer.html. I don't know how implements this.

But for sure you might need a subset of this solution for prev / next buttons. Either you are doing the *paging* by javascript and styling (e.g. css display property) or you are sending requests to the server.

You have two choices:

1. load all data in one page (your idea)
2. do an ajax request for every prev / next button press

My opinion:

1. All data just loaded once but this can be a huge amount of html to deliver to the client. Most of the time you edit one player and leave the page. This would be waste.
2. You have a clean page with only the needed data and can replace it by ajax call, fragment render and html replace. Downside: You get a server round trip for every *page*.

Maybe I got you wrong, but I read that you want to show just one player at a time. I know it is not an technical answer for your problem but a) it is too long for a comment b) it is something to think about before forcing the one list request.

Comment: Hmm yes, You're right :) I don't think about to send one element to view. Option nr 2 is nice and optimal for loading data from database but I still don't have idea how to...  But I'll try with paging like mate above says