# Thymeleaf Loop Until a Number

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I make a search and get response from server with Thymeleaf. This holds the number of results:

```
${response.count}
```

I want to make an iteration like that:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= response.count; i++) {
    if (response.page == i) {
        <button class="active">Dummy</button>
    } else {
        <button>Dummy</button>
    }
}
```

How can I do that? I've tried something like that:

```
${#numbers.sequence(0, response.count)}
```

but didn't work.

EDIT: I've tried that but didn't work too:

```
<button th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, response.count - 1)}" th:class="${i == response.page} ?: active">Dummy</button>
```

Comment: Is this what you're thinking about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490820/spring-thymeleaf-how-to-implement-pagination-for-a-list

Comment: Try this

<button th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, response.count - 1)}" th:class="${i == response.page} ? 'active'">Dummy</button>

I don't think you can use "?:" in this case, but "?" works fine.

Comment: I've accepted your answer but implemented as the way you commented, thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, response.count - 1)}">
    <button th:if="${response.page == i}" class="active">Dummy</button>
    <button th:unless="${response.page == i}">Dummy</button>
</th:block>
```

Comment: In my case instead of 'response.count' I use 'elements.size()' like this: 'th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, elements.size()- 1)}"'. Following this condition seems like the case when NO buttons are displayed is impossible. Minimum one button is displayed.